# Curve modifier problem with object

Tags: bezier-curves

so I want to attach this object to a curve while using a curve modifier. When I apply the modifier this happens
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello :). The curve modifier works best when both origin points are in the same place. If that won't help, consider [sharing your .blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so others can take a look.

Comment: Also you need more geometry along your object for it to curve realistically